# Custom Header Link Layout Update

Tags: layout, magento2.4, xml, header, headerlink

I have added the below code to app/design/frontend/Company/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml but the link is not appearing in the header. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

```
       <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="test.link" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">test</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">test</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

I see you people making a custom block but I don't see why you cannot use the the native Link block.

Answer (score 2):

I have added default.xml file with your given code on path  `app/code/Vender/Extension/view/frontend/layout/`

And Happily, it's working and redirects to the given path "test".and also display heder link as "test".[image]

Answer (score 1):

Andersen,

Your code is working great and I also prefer the xml rather then html blocks.
here is my screenshot, you can see you test link in the header.

- sometime there is cache problem with magento, so please clear the cache, please use below two given commands and check again, it should work fine.

  ```
   php bin/magento cache:flush
  ```

  ```
   chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/*
  ```

Please like if you find it useful.
[image]